# Symfony homepage not displaying image

Tags: php, symfony1

I created a Symfony project and I can access it from a web browser but it doesn't display any images.

I get this instead "If you see no image in this page, you may need to configure your web server so that it gains access to the symfony_data/web/sf/ directory."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to load the common images from the symfony installation itself.

To make this work you'll need [update your virtual host entry or make a symlink](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/03-Running-Symfony#chapter_03_sub_setting_up_a_virtual_host)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a symbolic link named "sf" in your DocumentRoot that links to SF_DIR/data/web/sf.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I solved this by copying the SF_DIR/data/web/sf to my project root.

Comment: Yyou're welcome. But it's recommended not just copy, but make a link for future compatibility.